# Excel VBA Code Completion (Methods|Properties)

Tags: excel, vba

Scenario
    Win7 SP1, Excel 2010, VBA Code, In a Module, Inside a Sub

Why if I type

**Application**
 A popup list with available Objects, Methods, Properties is presented
            (ActiveSheet is one of the options)

But if I type

**Application.ActiveSheet**
(No popup appears, I was looking for ‘Range’ )

Is there a way to "fix/get" it?

Comment: ActiveSheet returns a Variant type (or is it object type). You have to cast it to Worksheet for the system to know what type it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Dim wksht As Worksheet
 Set wksht = ActiveSheet 'I do not think you need the Application here
```

Then you can access all of the methods via `wksht.`

Comment: Actually, `Set wksht = ActiveSheet`

Comment: @chris Thanks, Chris.  Sharp eye as usual.

Comment: Dim wksht As Worksheet
Set wksht = ActiveSheet

Comment: @jonsca, do note though that activesheet can also be something other than a `worksheet` if you have a chartsheet selected your code will bomb, not a biggy as this is not very common, but something to keep in mind non-the-less this is the reason that activesheet does not have a fixed type, but is a variant instead.

Comment: @Johan Thank you, I did not think of that possibility